# Hibernate Search -- Closing MultiReader

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

Recenty when I use hibernate search, there is always an information:

```
DEBUG MultiReaderFactory - Closing MultiReader: CacheableMultiReader(ReadOnlyDirectoryReader(segments_1:nrt _0(3.6.2):C295103))
```

I didn't find any useful information in Google.Does anyone have ideas???

I found that after the query clause :

```
CacheQuery cq = CSECore.searchManager.getQuery(query,Entity.class).projection("id");
```

When it executes:

```
List<Object> list = cq.list();
```

Sometimes it works, sometimes it blocked like 10mins, but the result always correct. 
I'm not sure whether there is relation between they 2.

Comment: That's missing a bunch of information for us to really answer this question: what Hibernate Search and Lucene version is that? How do you trigger that debug message? When you say "recently", did it work "normally" before and what did you change?

Comment: I'm sry for the absent information. I used Hibernate Search 4.4.0 and Lucene 3.6.2. I have modified a lot and I can't remember where cause the problem. I have modified the question.

Comment: How do you know it takes 10 minutes? And that message is at DEBUG level, you can ignore it unless you think you have a problem with the closing operation.